# c# thread blocking ui when using wia

Tags: c#, multithreading, wia

I have a thread, that runs a method in another class, that scanns using wia (`ImageFile i = (ImageFile)item.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatPNG);`).
My problem is, that the thread is blocking my UI. Does anyone know how to do this without blocking the UI?

Edit:
Ok, More Code:

```
ImageFile imageFile;
public void Scan() {
Scanner s = new Scanner();
}

public void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     new Thread(Scan).Start();
}

public class Scanner {
ImageFile imagefile;
public Scanner() {
CommonDialogClass dlg = new CommonDialogClass();
Device nDevice = dlg.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, false, false);
Item nItem = nDevice.Items[1];
imagefile = (ImageFile)nItem.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatPNG);
//Do something with imagefile (works fine)
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post more (source) code, so we can provide you solutions? It's hard to say what causes the problem. Maybe your thread is taking CPU time away from the UI thread.

Comment: Show us how you're calling this code?